# What’s the difference between useState and useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have seen these two new concepts introduced in react v16.

As per my understanding:

> `useState` is similar like `setState` with hooks and `useEffect` works similarly like life cycle methods.

Is my understanding correct? If not, what’s the exact difference between `useState` and `useEffect`?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To put it simply, both `useState` and `useEffect` enhance functional components to make them do things that classes can but functional components (without hooks) cannot:

- `useState` allows functional components to have **state**, like `this.state` in class components.
- `useEffect` allows functional components to have **lifecycle methods** (such as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount`) in one single API.

---

Refer to the examples below for further illustration:

### `useState`

```js
class CounterClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 1 };
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      <p>Count: {this.state.count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ 
        count: this.state.count + 1
      })}>Increase</button>
    </div>;
  }
}

function CounterFunction() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => 
        setCount(count + 1)}
      >Increase</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <CounterClass />
    <CounterFunction />
  </div>
, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

### `useEffect`

```js
class LifecycleClass extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Mounted');
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('Will unmount');
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>Lifecycle Class</div>;
  }
}

function LifecycleFunction() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Mounted');
    return () => {
      console.log('Will unmount');
    };
  }, []); // Empty array means to only run once on mount.
  return (
    <div>Lifecycle Function</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <LifecycleClass />
    <LifecycleFunction />
  </div>
, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Read more about [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) on the official React docs.

Answer (score 28):

### For `useState()`

First, we have the *functional component* which did not supported `state`, in other words, a *functional component* is a *stateless component*.

Now, with Hooks, we have the *functional component* but **stateful**. It is achieved by using [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

---

### For `useEffect()`

First, with *stateless functional component*, we didn't have *component lifecycle hooks*. In other words, whenever you want to use *component lifecycle hooks*, you should consider using *class component*.

Now, we are able to use *component lifecycle hooks* without using *class component*. It is achieved by using [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). In other words, now whenever we want to use *component lifecycle hooks*, we already have two options either using *class component* or using Hooks with `useEffect`.

---

**UPDATE**

> what’s the exact difference between `useState` and `useEffect`?

In simple words, `useState` allows our *functional components* which used to be **stateless** become **stateful**. And `useEffect` allows our *functional components* leverage the *component lifecycle hooks* which were, in the past, only supported for *class components*.

Comment: I'm new to React, and I wasn't aware that there are many ways to create a component in React. Even in the official documentation, I couldn't find information about all the different methods to create the component. However, now I have a better understanding of why useEffect is used in React. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

`useState` and `useEffect` are part of React 16.8+ hooks ecosystem which aims at providing Functional components the same functionality which previously was available only with class based components (`state` / `setState` and component life cycle methods (ex. `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`)

`useState()` is straight forward, it lets you have state-accessors inside a functional component.

`useEffect()`  can combine `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` but is tricky.

You can decipher most of what I have to discuss here from official docs for [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). It’s easier to see hooks at work, than to reason from text.

#### **Pre-render lifecycle**

**Pre-render lifecycle** events equivalent to `componentWillReceiveProps` or `getDerivedStateFromProps` and `componentWillMount` can just be the things we do first in the functional component before returning JSX (react-node) as the function itself is equivalent to `render(…)` method of class based component.

***We don’t need hooks handling Pre-render lifecycle events.***

#### **Post-render lifecycle**

**Post-render lifecycle** events, those equivalent to `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidUnmount` in class based component.

***We need to* **`**_useEffect(…)_**`** *to handle these Post-render lifecycle events*** as we can’t write the logic tied to these lifecycle events inside the main component function as these should run after the component function returns JSX (react-node) to `react-dom` renderer.

This means, we have lot we can do with hooks. How?

We know `useEffect(fn, […watchStates])`, takes in 2 arguments.

1. `fn`: (required) `useEffect` invokes this function to run as side-effect after every render cycle based on values being tracked for changes given by the (2) argument. The function `fn`, could return another function that should be run as a cleanup before the effect function runs again or component un-mounts
2. `[…watchValues ]`: (optional) `useEffect` tracks values in this array has changed from the last render cycle then only effect `fn` is invoked. If this argument is not given, the effect will run with every render cycle.

If we don’t pass the (2) argument all-together, the effect logic in `fn` will be invoked after every render cycle.

If we pass (2) array with values the component needs to watch for changes, and invoke `fn` on change, pretty self explanatory.

The trickiest part is in using an empty array `[]` as the (2) argument, we can restrict side-effect logic in `fn` to execute only during the mounting phase as there are no changes effect hook would be watching for after subsequent render-cycles to trigger `fn` again.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default props => {
  console.log("componentWillMount");
  console.log("componentWillReceiveProps", props);
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = useState(0);
  const [moveCount, setMoveCount] = useState(0);
  const [cross, setCross] = useState(0);
  const mouseMoveHandler = event => {
    setX(event.clientX);
    setY(event.clientY);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);
    return () => {
      console.log("componentDidUnmount");
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);
    };
  }, []); // empty-array means don't watch for any updates
  useEffect(
    () => {
      // if (componentDidUpdate & (x or y changed))
      setMoveCount(moveCount + 1);
    },
    [x, y]
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    // if componentDidUpdate
    if (x === y) {
      setCross(x);
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <p style={{ color: props.color }}>
        Your mouse is at {x}, {y} position.
      </p>
      <p>Your mouse has moved {moveCount} times</p>
      <p>
        X and Y positions were last equal at {cross}, {cross}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The code snippet is simple and self explanatory. You can try it out on [CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/q38wpvvonq?fontsize=14).

One important thing to note is that if you are making a state change inside a effect, ensure you exclude the state that’s changing inside from the watch array.

For example in the second effect (one that counts the mouse movements) we only trigger it on updates on x and y, by passing `[x , y]` as the second argument because

1. Its logically correct to watch for changes to x and y to register a mouse movement
2. If we don’t exclude moveCount from being watched, this useEffect will go into an infinite cycle, as we will be updating the same value we are also watching for changes

---

This article is also aviable on my [**Medium**](https://medium.com/simars/react-hooks-manage-life-cycle-events-tricks-and-tips-7ed13f52ba12?source=friends_link&sk=1e75c8c90b14ba96ec94b114dfeeb54e) publication. If you like the artile, or have any comments and suggestions, please ***clap*** or leave ***comments*** on [**Medium**](https://medium.com/simars/react-hooks-manage-life-cycle-events-tricks-and-tips-7ed13f52ba12?source=friends_link&sk=1e75c8c90b14ba96ec94b114dfeeb54e).

Comment: I liked your answer as it was detailed with good explanation. However i see there are 2 eslint warnings related to useEffect on your CodePen example.  Is there a better way to structure code to get rid of these warnings? I will upvote this answer if you can suggest a way to clear those warnings.